# How to fix FileNotFoundException for a java jar file resource?

Tags: java, jar

I need to read up a zip file from inside my jar so I can pass it to the OpenOfficeSpellDictionary constructor.  Since the dictionary .zip file is inside the jar file I cannot create the new File reference with a URI like I can when the file is outside the jar.  It seems the right way to load a resource inside a jar is as an InputStream but I need to pass a File to the OpenOfficeSpellDictionary constructor.
The code now looks like this:

```
public static SpellDictionary forLanguage( MyLanguage lang ){
       String dictName = (String) props.get(lang.getLocale().getLanguage());
       if ( dictName != null ){
           if ( dicts.containsKey(lang) )
               return dicts.get(lang);
           System.out.println("loading dictionary for : " + lang);
           URL url = Dictionaries.class.getClassLoader().getResource(dictName);
           System.out.println(url);  //prints null
           try {
               System.out.println("loading dictionary for dictname : " + dictName);
               File zip = new File(url.toURI());
               OpenOfficeSpellDictionary dict = new OpenOfficeSpellDictionary(
                       new ZipFile(zip)
                       );
               dicts.put( lang, dict );

               return dict;
           } catch (Exception e){
               e.printStackTrace();
               dicts.put( lang, null );
           }
       }else{
           System.out.println("dictname is null " );            
       }
       return null;
   }
```

and it prints out :

```
loading dictionary for : English
null
loading dictionary for dictname : dict/en_US.zip
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.jl.nwn.spell.Dictionaries.forLanguage(Dictionaries.java:58)
```

or sometimes when I use a slightly different URI:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: jar:file:/Users/myname/Dev/MyProject/myjar.jar!/resource/dict/en_US.zip (No such file or directory)
```

I have tried a for dictName the strings /dict/en_US.zip, dict/en_US.zip, resource/dict/en_US.zip and /resource/dict/en_US.zip to no avail.
  A call to

```
InputStream is = Dictionaries.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(
                    "resource/dict/dictionaries.properties");
```

does work when I try to load the props.

Can I turn an InputStream into a File reference inside a jar file without creating a temp file somewhere? Would creating a temp file somewhere be horribly hacky if I could?

Comment: The question is why zipping anyway in jar file? Simple folder within jar would be better approach and serve it's point of arranging data files/ressources by some matter. What's the purpose of your approach?

Comment: Resources are not files. Rethink.

Comment: The project originally (and it is a very old project not of my own creation) had the zip files outside of the jar file - I am just trying to bring them inside the jar so the end user won't need to download the zip files separately.   I do not control the  OpenOfficeSpellDictionary api and it needs to use the zip files as zip files.  If it is not possible to do this with a fairly simple code change then I will revert the code as it is not a vital feature.